# Missing SQL entries when combining LEFT/INNER JOIN + GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have the following MySQL structure (minimized a lot):

```
CREATE TABLE `site_movies` (
  `id` int(10),
  `title` varchar(90),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `site_movies` VALUES(1, 'Borrowers, The');
INSERT INTO `site_movies` VALUES(2, 'Louis C.K.: Chewed Up');
INSERT INTO `site_movies` VALUES(3, 'Louis C.K.: Shameless');
INSERT INTO `site_movies` VALUES(4, 'Vinni-Pukh');

CREATE TABLE `site_movies_directors` (
  `id` mediumint(8),
  `name` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `site_movies_directors_connections` (
  `movie_id` mediumint(8),
  `director_id` mediumint(8)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `site_movies_seen` (
  `object_id` int(10),
  `date` varchar(10),
  `rating` tinyint(2)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `site_movies_seen` VALUES(1, '0', 4);
INSERT INTO `site_movies_seen` VALUES(2, '1293821757', 5);
INSERT INTO `site_movies_seen` VALUES(3, '1293821758', 7);
INSERT INTO `site_movies_seen` VALUES(4, '0', 6);
```

And then the following query (also minimized a lot):

```
SELECT m.title, s.date
FROM site_movies_seen s
INNER JOIN site_movies m ON s.object_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN site_movies_directors_connections AS mdc ON ( m.id = mdc.movie_id ) 
GROUP BY mdc.movie_id, s.date
ORDER BY s.date ASC
```

Prints:

```
title   date 
Borrowers, The  0
Louis C.K.: Chewed Up   1293821757
Louis C.K.: Shameless   1293821758
```

Notice that "Vinni-Pukh" is missing because it is the second entry in the _seen table with date = 0. How can I include all entires, even when several entires have the same timestamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your group by statement to this:

```
GROUP BY m.id, s.date
```

Your join condition says `m.id = mdc.movie_id`, so you might think that these two fields are always equal and therefore it doesn't matter whether you write `m.id` or `mdc.movie_id` in your GROUP BY. This is not true because you are using a LEFT JOIN, not an INNER JOIN. This means that `mdc.movie_id` can be NULL, and all NULL entries go into the same group.

Also, since you aren't selecting any columns from the `site_movies_directors_connections` you should omit it from the query completely.

```
SELECT m.title, s.date
FROM site_movies_seen s
INNER JOIN site_movies m ON s.object_id = m.id
GROUP BY m.id, s.date
ORDER BY s.date
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark! Changing mdc.movie_id into m.id did the trick. Regarding the director stuff, that's just a result of some over-minimized code from my part ;-)